# How do I get Keras to train a model on a specific GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

There is a shared server with 2 GPUs in my institution. Suppose there are two team members each wants to train a model at the same time, then how do they get Keras to train their model on a specific GPU so as to avoid resource conflict?

Ideally, Keras should figure out which GPU is currently busy training a model and then use the other GPU to train the other model. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. It seems that by default Keras only uses the first GPU (since the `Volatile GPU-Util` of the second GPU is always 0%).

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Possibly duplicate with my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52444944/6280540)

It's a bit more complicated. Keras will the memory in both GPUs althugh it will only use one GPU by default. Check `keras.utils.multi_gpu_model` for using several GPUs.

I found the solution by choosing the GPU using the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES.

You can add this manually before importing keras or tensorflow to choose your gpu

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" # first gpu
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1" # second gpu
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1" # runs in cpu
```

To make it automatically, I made a function that parses `nvidia-smi` and detects automatically which GPU is being already used and sets the appropriate value to the variable.

Comment: Great! Thank you! This is exactly what I want!

Comment: This isn't practical for a program that does a lot of stuff... is there another way?

Comment: I'll be glad if someone find an easier one!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a training script you can simply set it in the command line before invoking the script

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python train.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to train models on cloud GPUs (e.g. GPU instances from AWS), try this library:

```
!pip install aibro==0.0.45 --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple

from aibro.train import fit
machine_id = 'g4dn.4xlarge' #instance name on AWS
job_id, trained_model, history = fit(
    model=model,
    train_X=train_X,
    train_Y=train_Y,
    validation_data=(validation_X, validation_Y),
    machine_id=machine_id
)
```

Tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19sXZ4kbic681zqEsrl_CZfB5cegUwuIB#scrollTo=ERqoHEaamR1Y